# Appropriate to ask for advice on taking a specific training course?

Tags: discussion

Would posting a question that solicits opinions/reviews on a specific training course be acceptable on this site? I'm wondering whether it's worth my time or not and want to see if anyone in the community has taken it. I'm not sure if it's appropriate or not, so thought I'd ask first.

Edit: Let me be clear and transparent. My question would be something along the lines of:

**Has anyone taken --insert course name and url here--? I'm considering it and want honest opinions/reviews of those who have attended it.**

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of in the gray zone for me. But I guess it would be fine as a CW question to ask for review of a course, as long as it doesn't start a lengthy argument.